# Understanding various Tools used in Azure DevSecOps

Tags: azure-devops

I am looking for the various Tools that can be used in a Azure DevSecOps utilizing Devops pipeline.
So for example for each of the stage of security scanning or tools that can be used, please refer my diagram.
SCA - Software Composition Analysis can use tools like Whitesource, but what else ?
SAST - which tools ? Artifact Scanning - what tools
DAST - Scanning tools What else ?
What am I missing in the diagram ?
Appreciate any response to enhance my understanding.

[Azure DevsecOps Overview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pYkCG.png)

I did check various links like this - https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/securityengineering/devsecops
But none of them provide me a comprehensive List of options or step by step details towards which tools can be used at different stage of the DevSecOPS.

Comment: DevSecOps integrate security into every aspect of the software delivery lifecycle. It leverage CI and CD of container images securely. I'm not quite sure which tools you are trying to understand. You may check this link: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/solutions/devsecops/

Comment: Thank you Cece for responding.

Comment: Thank you Cece for responding. I did look into that link as well, However, like I mentioned in my query , I am looking for the Microsoft internal and Microsoft supported third party scanning tools that can be integrated with the pipelines for SCA,SAST,DAST,Automated PenTesting,etc. I can see there are tools like Whitesource,Synopses,etc mentioned in various tutorials but a single place that provides every security checkpoints, tools that need to be defined ( again please refer my diagram.. Let me know if you are still unsure ?

Comment: If you want to use tools as task in Azure Pipeline, it could be achieved by using command task. If you want to use tools in DevSecOPS, I'm afraid this requirement is not able to be achieved.